# Find the transition matrix. What is $p \in \mathbb R_3[x]$ if $[p]_{S'} = (-1,2,1)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the transition matrix from a basis $S = \{1,x,x^2, x^3 \}$ of $\mathbb R_3[x]$ to

$S'= \{1,x+1,(x+1)^2, (x+1)^3 \}$.

What is $p \in \mathbb R_3[x]$ if $[p]_{S'} = (-1,2,1)^T$?

Is there not a mistake here?

This is what I did:

$1=(1)1+(0)x+(0)x^2+(0)x^3$

$x+1 = (1)1+(1)x+(0)x^2+(0)x^3$

$(x+1)^2 = x^2+2x+1 =(1)1+(2)x+(1)x^2+(0)x^3$

$(x+1)^3 = (x^2+2x+1)(x+1) = x^3+3x^2+3x+1 = (1)1+(3)x+(3)x^2+(1)x^3$

$T= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now surely

$T^{-1}p = [p]_{S'}$

So $p = T[p]_{S'}$

but $T$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix and $[p]_{S'}$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix so surely this multiplication is undefined and they need to give a $4 \times 1$ matrix instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get $p = (2,4,1,0)^T = 2 + 4 x + x^2$. I took the liberty to extend $p'=(-1,2,1)^T$ to $(-1,2,1,0)^T$ and then used $p = T p'$.

Testing:

\begin{align}
(-1)\cdot 1 + (2)\cdot (x+1) + (1) \cdot (x+1)^2
&= -1 + 2x + 2 + x^2 + 2x + 1 \\
&= (2)\cdot 1 + (4)\cdot x + (1)\cdot x^2
\end{align}

Comment: So we can just extend it that way? Why is that?

Comment: Oh is it because an extra row column in a matrix is not necessary if it contains only zeros

Comment: Lets try to verify it. $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ are the polynomials $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3$ with real coefficients. What is $[p]_{S'}$, the coordinates of $p$ regarding base $S'$?

Comment: Oh yeah I see so $a_3 = 0$

Comment: Hm, I probably should have used $T$ instead.

Comment: Yeah now I agree with your answer :) thanks